# Getting frame dimension from raw mpeg4 stream?

Tags: c#, video-processing, mpeg-4

does anyone know how i can retrieve the frame dimension of a mpeg4 video (non h264, i.e. Mpeg4 Part 2) from the raw video bitstream? 
i´m currently writing a custom media source for windows media foundation, i have to provide a mediatype which needs the frame size. it doesn´t work without it.
any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not getting you. Are you trying to know the width and the height of the video being streamed? If so (and I guess that it is the "dimension" you are looking for) heres how:

1. Parse the stream for this integer `000001B0`(hex) its always the first thing you get streamed. If not, see the SDP of the stream (if you have any, and search for `config=` field, and there it is... only now it is a Base16 string!
2. Read all the bytes until you get to the integer `000001B6`(hex)
3. You should get something like this (hex): `000001B0F5000001B5891300000100000001200086C40FA28 A021E0A2`
4. This is the "stream configuration header" or frame or whatever, exact name is Video Object Sequence. It holds all the info a decoder would need to decode the video stream.
5. Read the last 4 bytes (in my example they are separated by one space -- `A021E0A2`)
6. Now observe these bytes as one 32-bit unsigned integer...
7. To get **width** read the first 8 bits, and then **multiply what you get with 4**
8. Skip next 7 bits
9. To get **height** read next 9 bits
10. In pseudo code:

    ```
      WIDTH = readBitsUnsigned(array, 8) * 4;
      readBitsUnsigned(array, 7);
      HEIGHT = readBitsUnsigned(array, 9);
    ```

There you go... width and height. (:

Comment: Is this correct?  I'm trying to decode frames of a stream I know is 1280x1024.  With this logic, the width can't be above 1020, and height can't be above 511.

Comment: WIDTH should multiply by 8 instead of 4, and HEIGHT should multiply by 2 also for that integer read from last 5 bytes instead of 4 bytes.